# Xpath for child tag

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<div class="hello1">
    <a href="random/url/hi" class="title">random text</a> 
</div>
```

I want to get the URL "random/url/hi" and I wrote this XPATH to get it: //div[@class="hello1"]/a[1]

The text inside the < /a> tags are always changing so I can't rely on that. I also don't know if there is another class attribute with "title" so I can't use that either. All I know is I want the first < /a> tag inside the div class "hello1"

Why isn't my XPATH working? Can someone help me write another expression?

Comment: I think the path is fine to select the `a` element, but you say you want the URL so `//div[@class = 'hello']/a[1]/@href` seems more appropriate. If the path you does not select anything then you need to provide more details on the input XML and the XPath API you use.

Comment: *"Why isn't my XPATH working?"* - My crystal ball says because you are dealing with XHTML and forgot to use the proper namespace in your XPath expression.

Comment: Do you need any further help?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the href this way.

```
//div[@class='hello1']/a[1]/@href
```

Comment: With XPath the index starts with 1, not with 0, so the path as posted seems to be fine to select the first `a` child element.

Comment: Sorry was my mistake i didnt think when i posted that. i have changed my answer and tested on xpath tester. This is right now.